Compare two Excel spreadsheets & clean up duplicates
I've got two datasets: "A1" (the complete set, though it has duplicate lines) and "A2" (the one I shall be using to cross reference with A1 to identify which lines are duplicates).
So, in short, I need A2 to somehow be able to highlight the duplicate lines in A1, AND THEN eliminate one of those lines in A1.

In this image, these are two duplicate lines in A1 which I highlighted manually, having compared with the data in A2.
I've tried the remove duplicates function in Excel, though it's no use seeing as I NEED to make sure the duplicates are the ones in A2.
Have tried the INDEX function, but made no head nor tails of that one.
Have tried this Compare two excel sheets and this is what I came up with:
=SE(ÉERRO(PROCV($E11;'Pagamentos Pix'!$E$11:$E$2015;1;FALSO)),"PGTO PIX","")
Edit: I've been trying the VLOOKUP/PROCX function as suggested, and yet nothing so far. I'm thinking the argument is valid, so no idea where the mistake is.

=PROCX(E11;$Q$11:$Q$2015;"PIX";"NÃO";0)
Any further help? (I've moved the table to somewhere in the vicinity so I could make the whole interval thing easier, btw. It was originally in a different file.)

If you're trying to compare two tables using a unique identifier and remove the duplicate codes from one of the tables, you can simply use a lookup to identify the matches and non-matches.
In the image below, I put together a very simple example where I put codes into two lists/tables, and I did a vlookup (formula on image and I'll share below). Each of the values that pulled a code has a match all the #N/A do not have matches. You can then sort by this column and delete the rows that contain the matching values.
=VLOOKUP(A3,$E$3:$E$15,1,0)
=VLOOKUP( [lookup value], [Table A2, starting with the code column], 1,0)
The lookup value is the key you're searching for
the second condition is where you want the formula to search for that value
The third is which column from the first column should it search (if you only highlight the code column, 1 will work)
The last is exact match because we only want codes that match.


As i'm sure it's obvious, this is the english version of excel, so be mindful seperators for your region may be ; instead of , and the word for the formula may vary.

Thank you for your swift response! And yes, I'm aware of the local differences, it's no problem.

I've tried your suggestion but no idea where I'm doing wrong, as I think the phrasing is totally valid? I'm going to edit my original comment.

@sublondon i think it needed to be: =SE(ÉERRO(PROCV($E11;'Pagamentos Pix'!$E$11:$E$2015;1;FALSO),"PGTO PIX"),"") You had the parenthesis in the wrong position or =PROCX(E11;$Q$11:$Q$2015;$Q$11:$Q$2015 ;"NÃO";0) the xlookup needs a search column as well as a return column.
